# Why unicode symbols cannot be shown for XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, unicode, xecjk

I have following example, which I would the unicode symbols to be shown automatically, how should I do? Please kindly help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
  你好! ⃝ ⃞
\end{document}
```

Just to let you know, the circle is #20DD, and the square is #20DE.

Comment: I don't know. But I can obtain symbols by changing
a font: `\setmainfont{Source Han Sans SC Regular}`.

Comment: No font contains all of Unicode so you need to switch fonts if you use lots of characters from different scripts.  The log file will warn about any characters not in the font.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the environment in which you work: The editor/terminal's font doesn't have the required glyphs to display the offending characters. Might need to change the font used. Another thing altogether is if the font used in the document has the required glyphs. That is a completely separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSerifCJKtc-Regular} % Choose any chinese (sc or tc) font of your choice.

\begin{document}
  你好! ⃝ ⃞
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a missing-character-in-used-font problem. See the log file

```
Missing character: There is no ⃝ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ⃞ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

Unfortunately, usually these log lines are not caught by editors.

Setting a (non-CJK) font which contains the required characters fix OP's problem, as other answer do.